# Undo changes in git's uncommitted but staged file

Tags: git, version-control

How can I revert `make.f90` (I tried `git revert`) it to previous version?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   make.f90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To discard staged changes:

```
git reset HEAD make.f90
```

Another way is:

```
git stash save
git stash drop
```

You can stash all your changes and then you drop them.